# RijndaelManaged Specified key is not a valid size for this algorithm

Tags: c#, sql, encryption, aes, rijndaelmanaged

```
 using (RijndaelManaged rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged())  
        rijAlg.Key = Key;
        rijAlg.IV = IV;
```

This gives me an error "Specified key is not a valid size for this algorithm."

to get Key and IV

```
    string checkPass = "select password from UserName where Username = '" + TBLoginUser.Text + "'";
    SqlCommand pass = new SqlCommand(checkPass, conn);
    string password = pass.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

    string checkKey = "select encKey from UserName where Username = '" + TBLoginUser.Text + "'";
    SqlCommand k = new SqlCommand(checkKey, conn);
    string key = k.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

    string checkIV = "select encIV from UserName where Username = '" + TBLoginUser.Text + "'";
    SqlCommand x = new SqlCommand(checkIV, conn);
    string iv = x.ExecuteScalar().ToString();



    byte[] keyByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
    byte[] ivByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(iv);
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: Well, what are the contents of `key` and `iv`?

Comment: I'm so naming my username ';drop table UserName

Comment: `using (RijndaelManaged rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged()) rijAlg.Key = Key; rijAlg.IV = IV;` are you missing a brackets `using (..) {...  }`

Comment: The error is very clear, the size of the key is invalid, Rijndael key must be 128, 192 or 256 bits length

Comment: What @OndrejSvejdar is trying to say is that you should use prepared statements to prevent SQL injections, because your current code is vulnerable to them.

Comment: How do change the size of the key? @Gusman

Comment: Passwords should be hashed not encrypted.  If you can decrypt them, so can a Bad Guy

Comment: Ehm... create an array of 16, 24 or 32 bytes... *byte[] keyByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);* key for sure is not 16, 24 or 32 chars length, ant thus keyByte is not 16, 24 or 32 bytes length.

Comment: byte[] keyByte = new byte[32];
 keyByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key); @Gusman

Comment: No, that will write keyByte with the result, it will not preserve the size, you should hash the key string which will yield a 16 or 32 bytes result

Comment: @Gusman can you give me an example? I am not so sure how to do so.

Comment: Of course, open your browser, navigate to google and type "C# hashing" (return).

Comment: You should use a password based key derivation function to go from a string to a key. Options would be PBKDF2 and bcrypt. [PBKDF2 has an implementation in .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Building on @MaartenBodewes comments, it's best not to try to "roll your own" security.  Check out something like: http://securitydriven.net/inferno/